# Why does the error "source not found" occur in my case?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a problem in Eclipse Java where I got an error that is "source not found". 

May I know what is the error as I have checked that the path, and it seems correct however when I run the program, it terminated.

```
String Path = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
FileReader csvFile = new FileReader(Path+"/src/login_sessions.csv");
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you add the exception stacktrace to your question?. Are you getting `FileNotFoundException`?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do; open a file at "./src/login_sessions.csv"? Did you try printing out the path you did get? And what exactly gives you "source not found" - a csv file is not a "source"?

Comment: why did you make that Path variable?

Comment: Why not just doing: `FileReader csvFile = new FileReader("/src/login_sessions.csv");` ?

Comment: Hi Jay, I'm quite new to Eclipse, hence I'm not sure whether do I need to pass an argument.

Comment: Hi TheLostMind, no exception was caught, it just terminated the program.

Comment: Hi breezee, it gave me this error - `java.io.FileNotFoundException: \src\login_sessions.csv (The system cannot find the path specified)`

Comment: @Jane - Then can you add the error that you keep getting to your question?

Comment: @TheLostMind, only when I debug it shows "Source not found". When I run the code normally. no error was shown

Comment: @Jane - That means you are trying to step into a class's function while debugging whose source code is not available.

Comment: @breezee Because that path is ___obviously___ different to what OP uses!

Comment: @Jay He passes an argument and that empty String a valid one. You can test `new File("").getAbsolutePath()` to see what it yields.

Comment: @Jay Looks like you don't know that. An empty file resolves to the current path and that makes sense since OP tries to use an absolute path for the `FileReader` initialization. He could also use a relative path, but OPs current version isn't as wrong as you try to say.

Comment: @Jay It works as expected. Big surprise. Maybe some research would help you here :).

Comment: @Jay Now its getting awkward. It obviously doesn't throw such exception if you either rebuild your local file structure to have a file in your source folder with the name `login_sessions.csv` or if you adjust the `/src/login_sessions.csv`. It might be the case the OP made a mistake by using `/src/login_sessions.csv`, but that doesn't change the fact that using an empty String in the `File` constructor is not an issue.

Comment: @Jay An exception, not an error and I don't know his file structure and where the file actually is. But, again, that doesn't rectify your wrong, first comment.

Comment: @Jay Yes, correct, on a site like Stack Overflow where people want ___correct___ information, it is very inappropriate if comment on incorrect stuff.

Comment: @Jay That wasn't the important part of these comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
File csvFile = new File("src/login_sessions.csv");
System.out.println("opening file at " + csvFile.getAbsolutePath());
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(csvFile)) {
    // do your thing
}
```

Does the path it outputs match what you expect? It may be executed at a location you don't expect.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 File f;
    f = new File(getClass().getResource("/mockJson.json").getFile());
    FileReader csvFile = new FileReader(f);
```

mockJson.json stored in src